# How do I get .NET Feature Management to use config in User Secrets?

Tags: .net, user-secret

I've got an ASPNET Core web app (.NET 6). I have User Secrets enabled and Feature Management enabled.

I would like to override some flags in my user secrets. However, by default, Feature Management reads from the `FeatureManagement` section of config, but doesn't read from user secrets.

How do I get FeatureManagement to read from user secrets as well as other config sources?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have [set up your project for User Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows), you simply have to call `AddUserSecrets` when building your configuration.

This is automatically done for you when using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`, but isn't if you manually initialise the builder (*several hours could be lost if you forget this important fact - ask me how I know...*)